# Pass or access a variable from service to service in android

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I need a variable accessed and updated by two or more services or activities. I am thinking of using interface. A class that implements that interface to be initialized in Base Application class or via hilt. I am not entirely sure how to do that.

1. Is this possible and if so, is this good idea?
2. Can I use any other way to pass variable from service to service or activity to service?

Possible psuedoCode for idea.

```
interface foo(){
      variable a
      fun setA(var : p)
}

class JustAClass: foo{
    variable a;
 fun setA(var : p){
  
  a = p
 
 }
}

BaseApp(): Application(){
  JustAClass jac = JustAClass();
}

activityA(){
  BaseApp.jac.setA(99)
}

serviceB(){
   variable c = BaseApp.jac.a
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could do it the way you describe, but there are a few easier ways...

**You can use a Singleton**. In Kotlin, any Object is automatically a statically accessible Singleton. So, something like this:

```
object SharedData{
    var item1 = "test"
    var item2 = false
}
```

can be accessed anywhere in your app by using `SharedData.item1` or `SharedData.item2`. You can also make those variables into `LiveData` or `Kotlin Flow` if you want to post updates and observe them between activities/services/etc.

**You can also store your data in SharedPreferences**. It'll provide more permanent storage that will survive app restarts, but it reads and writes data to internal storage, so you need to deal with IO overhead.

You can also store your data in other permament data structures, like a `Room Database`, but I think that would be overkill for just communicating between processes.